# Вывод индексов и подстрок в текстовых полях в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, format, richtextbox

Доброго времени суток!

Есть задача: в строке часть текста должна идти в "надстрочном" виде, как , например, знак степени рядом с числом. Пробовал зайти через rich text, но там такой тип форматирования не поддерживается.

Посоветуйте какой-нибудь, лучше некоммерческий :) вариант. 
Спасибо.

Comment: свой шрифт можно нарисовать например, и нужные символы сделать как надо

Comment: Используйте TextMeshPro